# Movielens dataset most preferred movie genre

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I'm working with the MovieLens 100K dataset. I would like to have a graph visualizing the most preferred movie genres for the female users. For now that works by summing up how many times they have given a rating for a movie in the specific genre (meaning they have engaged with the genre). However, considering that some of the female users have given way more ratings than others maybe the results are not very true. Maybe there was one female user that really liked 'Drama' and gave 100 ratings to that. What is a way to normalize that data and to have a true representation of what are the most preferred genres?

```
plt.figure(figsize=(18,10))
for column in all_female_users[['Action', 'Adventure' , 'Animation' ,
              'Childrens' , 'Comedy' , 'Crime' , 'Documentary' , 'Drama' , 'Fantasy' ,
              'Film-Noir' , 'Horror' , 'Musical' , 'Mystery' , 'Romance' , 'Sci-Fi' ,
              'Thriller' , 'War' , 'Western']]:
   # Select column contents by column name using [] operator
    columnSeriesObj = all_female_users[column]

    plt.bar(column, columnSeriesObj.sum())
    plt.xlabel("Movie Genre")
    plt.ylabel("Number of preferred times")
    plt.title("Most preferred movie genres by women")
#     print('Movie Genre:', column)
#     print('Move Genre Sum:', columnSeriesObj.sum())
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your method sums absolute instead of relative values.

For each female user, you can "normalize" between all genres. For example, if one female user rates 50 dramas and 50 comedies, then you convert this to 0.5 in drama, and 0.5 in comedy. In the case of a female user rating 100 drama movies, if this is the only genre she rates, then this is converted to 1.0, which would be the same as if he had only rated 50 drama movies or just 1 drama movie - this method ensures that a user who rates 100 movies doesn't overrepresent this category when you sum all of these normalized values.